# Can I create custom exceptions with another exception (similar to "causedby" in Java)

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

I am working on a framework and writing extensions to it.

The problem is that I only have to **raise** a particular class of `Exception` for the framework.

```
class FrameworkException(Exception):
```

I can raise an `Exception` which is the a subclass of `FrameworkException` and the framework will take care of logging/reporting the exception.

Now, in my plugin I can get a variety of exceptions, let's say a `ValueError`. Can I create a `FrameworkException` with all the details of `ValueError` somehow?

In Java, I will do something like this,

```
catch (IOException e) {
    throw new FrameworkException(e);
}
```

In this way, all the details of the original exception `e` will be preserved including the **message** and **stacktrace** like this,

```
Exception in thread "main" FrameworkException: IOException: Custom Message
    at com.Test.main(Test.java:115)
Caused by: IOException: Custom Message
    at com.Test.main(Test.java:113)
```

Is something similar possible in Python?

I tried,

```
except Exception as e:
    raise FrameworkException(e)
```

But it lost the original traceback and had only the message.

I am using **Python 2.7** by the way.

Comment: Shame you're using Python 2; Python 3 has its [`raise <exception> from <cause>`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/).

Comment: @Evert, ya.. But they forgot about backward compatibility while making 3, so I can't switch easily...:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2 you can raise the your exception with the original traceback, so you shold write:

```
raise FrameworkException, FrameworkException(e), sys.exc_info()[2]
```

Or switch to a Python 3

Comment: Great. This seems to be working... Quick question, is there a way to include the original exception type also in this?

Comment: Forget it, I did `FrameworkException('%s:%s'%(type(e),e))` and it print's the original type too.